# Unity - UNET gameobject and child rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, rotation

I've been trying for hours to fix this but now I have no idea what's wrong. Here is a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8JrXwgvvFg As you can see my player is rotating and it's synced (as you can see by text above player), but the "hand" isn't and I don't know why. Can you help me?

**Client.cs:**

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text;
 using TMPro;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.Networking;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

 public class Player
 {
     public string playerName;
     public GameObject avatar;
     public int connectionID;
 }

 public class ClientManager : MonoBehaviour {

     private const int MAX_PLAYERS = 24;

     private int port = 5701;

     private int hostId;

     private int reliableChannel;
     private int unreliableChannel;

     private int clientID;
     private int connectionId;

     private float connectionTime;
     private bool isConnected = false;
     private bool isStarted = false;
     private byte error;

     private string playerName;

     public GameObject playerPrefab;
     public Dictionary<int, Player> players = new Dictionary<int, Player>();

     public void Connect()
     {
         string pName = GameObject.Find("NameInput").GetComponent<InputField>().text;
         if (pName == "")
         {
             Debug.LogError("You must type in your nickname before you connect!");
             return;
         }

         playerName = pName;

         NetworkTransport.Init();
         ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

         reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
         unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);

         HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_PLAYERS);

         hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, 0);
         connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostId, "127.0.0.1", port, 0, out error);

         connectionTime = Time.time;
         isConnected = true;
     }

     private void Update()
     {
         if (!isConnected)
             return;

         int recHostId;
         int connectionId;
         int channelId;
         byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
         int bufferSize = 1024;
         int dataSize;
         byte error;
         NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);
         switch (recData)
         {
             case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
                 string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuffer, 0, dataSize);
                 Debug.Log("Receiving: " + msg);
                 string[] splitdata = msg.Split('|');

                 switch (splitdata[0])
                 {
                     case "ASKNAME":
                         OnAskName(splitdata);
                         break;

                     case "CNN":
                         Debug.LogError(splitdata[1] + " connected!");
                         SpawnPlayer(splitdata[1], int.Parse(splitdata[2]));
                         break;

                     case "DC":
                         Debug.LogError(splitdata[1] + " disconnected!");
                         PlayerDisconnected(int.Parse(splitdata[2]));
                         break;

                     case "ASKPOSITION":
                         OnAskPosition(splitdata);
                         break;

                     default:
                         Debug.LogError("Wrong message: " + msg);
                         break;
                 }

                 break;
         }
     }
 private void OnAskPosition(string[] data)
     {
         if (!isStarted)
             return;

         //Update everyone else
         for (int i = 1; i < data.Length; i++)
         {
             string[] d = data[i].Split('%');
             //Prevent to server from updating us
             if (clientID != int.Parse(d[0]))
             {
                 Vector3 position = Vector3.zero;
                 position.x = float.Parse(d[1]);
                 position.y = float.Parse(d[2]);
                 position.z = float.Parse(d[3]);
                 players[int.Parse(d[0])].avatar.transform.position = position;

                 players[int.Parse(d[0])].avatar.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, float.Parse(d[4]), 0);
                 players[int.Parse(d[0])].avatar.transform.GetChild(0).rotation = Quaternion.Euler(float.Parse(d[5]), 0, 0);

                 Debug.LogWarning("THEIR Player rot: " + float.Parse(d[4]));
                 Debug.LogWarning("THEIR Camera rot: " + float.Parse(d[5]));
             }
         }

         //Send our own position
         Vector3 myPosition = players[clientID].avatar.transform.position;

         Debug.LogWarning("MY Player rot Y: " + players[clientID].avatar.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y.ToString());
         Debug.LogWarning("MY Cam rot X: " + players[clientID].avatar.transform.GetChild(0).rotation.eulerAngles.x.ToString());

         string m = "MYPOSITION|" + myPosition.x.ToString() + '|' + myPosition.y.ToString() + '|' + myPosition.z.ToString() + '|' + players[clientID].avatar.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y.ToString() + '|' + players[clientID].avatar.transform.GetChild(0).rotation.eulerAngles.x.ToString();
         Send(m, unreliableChannel);
     }
```

**Server.cs**

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.Networking;

 public class Players
 {
     public int connectionId;
     public string playerName;
     public Vector3 position;
     public float rotationPlayerY;
     public float rotationCameraX;
 }

 public class ServerManager : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private const int MAX_PLAYERS = 24;

     private int port = 5701;

     private int hostId;

     private int reliableChannel;
     private int unreliableChannel;

     private bool isStarted = false;
     private byte error;

     private List<Players> players = new List<Players>();

     private float lastmovementUpdate;
     private float movementUpdateRate = 0.05f;

     private void Start()
     {
         NetworkTransport.Init();
         ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

         reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
         unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);

         HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_PLAYERS);

         hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);

         isStarted = true;
     }

     private void Update()
     {
         if (!isStarted)
             return;

         int recHostId;
         int connectionId;
         int channelId;
         byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
         int bufferSize = 1024;
         int dataSize;
         byte error;
         NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);
         switch (recData)
         {
             case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
                 Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + " connected!");
                 PlayerConnect(connectionId);
                 break;

             case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
                 string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuffer, 0, dataSize);
                 Debug.Log("Receiving from " + connectionId + ": " + msg);
                 string[] splitdata = msg.Split('|');

                 switch (splitdata[0])
                 {
                     case "NAMEIS":
                         OnNameIs(connectionId, splitdata[1]);
                         break;

                     case "MYPOSITION":
                         OnMyPosition(connectionId, float.Parse(splitdata[1]), float.Parse(splitdata[2]), float.Parse(splitdata[3]));
                         OnMyRotation(connectionId, float.Parse(splitdata[4]), float.Parse(splitdata[5]));
                         break;

                     default:
                         Debug.LogError("Wrong message: " + msg);
                         break;
                 }
                 break;

             case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent:
                 Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + " disconnected!");
                 OnDisconnection(connectionId);
                 break;
         }

         //ask player for their position
         if(Time.time - lastmovementUpdate > movementUpdateRate && players.Count > 0)
         {
             lastmovementUpdate = Time.time;
             string m = "ASKPOSITION|";

             foreach (Players pl in players)
             {
                 //POSITION UPDATE
                 m += pl.connectionId.ToString() + '%' + pl.position.x.ToString() + '%' + pl.position.y.ToString() + '%' + pl.position.z.ToString() + '%' + pl.rotationPlayerY.ToString() + '%' + pl.rotationCameraX.ToString() + '|';
             }
             m = m.Trim('|');
             Send(m, unreliableChannel, players);
         }
     }
 private void OnMyPosition(int connID, float x, float y, float z)
     {
         players.Find(q => q.connectionId == connID).position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
     }

     private void OnMyRotation(int connID, float playerRot, float cameraRot)
     {
         players.Find(q => q.connectionId == connID).rotationCameraX = cameraRot;
         players.Find(q => q.connectionId == connID).rotationPlayerY = playerRot;
     }
```

Comment: `This video is unavailable.`

Comment: @Stefan Oops, sorry, fixed :)